# Ошибка в описании для stackoverflow на русском в выпадающем списке сайтов

Tags: дефект, локализация

Ошибка в описании для *stackoverflow на русском* в выпадающем списке сайтов.

Текущий текст:

**For программистов**

Ожидаемый текст:

**Для программистов**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже, что слово **for** используется по умолчанию для описания всех сообществ. Например, для японского *stackoverflow* написано:

**For プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人**.

Comment: Да, есть такая проблема, спасибо. Вроде уже был багрепорт об этом где-то...

Comment: @NickVolynkin собственно [вот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4040/176217). В комментах есть ссылка на Meta.SE. А в комментах на Meta.SE есть ссылка на мой [баг-репорт](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3680/176217), так что выбирайте какой-нибудь в качестве дубликата.